# which is the best way for fetching value from XML : JAXB or DOM?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, jaxb

Which one is the efficient way for reading xml. I'm aware of two ways:

1)JAXB:
By annotating my classes with jaxb annotation we get the xml in java object vice versa using Marshalling & Unmarshalling of object.

2)DOM:
Using dom parser for parsing the xml and using xpath values from xml can be accessed.

Example of DOM:

```
        File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/link1/input.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

As per the business demands, I'm expecting to use the fastest way and the better way between the above two. Suggestions and few tactics would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you required to use JAXB or DOM, or are SAX, StAX and Jackson XmlMapper also an option?

Comment: Your google foo would have told you the right answer. BUT.. if your xml is small ( think 500 MB ) go in place ( DOM ) otherwise go streaming ( SAX, StaX )

Comment: @toongeorges  Being a new user, I currently look forward to only these two options and falling short of time i need to pick one of them.

Comment: DOM loads the document on to your program memory so you can access all nodes, I think for building class JAXB is more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First question to ask: does your XML always have the same structure and can this structure be mapped on a hierarchy of Java objects?

1. If Yes -> either use JAXB or Jackson XmlMapper
2. If No (the structure of your XML varies) -> Do you require random access to the data in your XML with many reads and possibly some writes (after which you convert the data back to XML)?

   2.1. If Yes -> use DOM (It is designed for in memory handling of the XML Document Tree, but has more overhead)

   2.2. If No (more efficient XML parsing) -> Do you need to parse all information in the XML or do you need XML validation?

   - 2.2.1 If Yes -> use SAX (it is included in the JDK and allows for validation)
   - 2.2.2 If No -> use StAX (it is an XML pull parser that allows reading some values in the XML without having to parse the full XML, but it does not offer validation.)